# JavaScript Loops when calling Async

Tags: javascript, datamaps

Problem: JavaScript is able to successfully draw several arcs on the screen, but they disappear when run. I am running a simple loop calling the ARC function, I don't get it!?

All I want to do is run each call step by step and sleep! This could be done in any language outside of JavaScript with ease, its a simple procedural Loop.

The problem is my graph shows up for a split second before disappearing. However if I trace through the code via JavaScript debugger it works until it disappears again!

Frustrated! I tried to wrap this with a timeOut, so I can sleep to show a slow animation.  What on earth is going on my friends, is this a bug in JavaScript or are my fundamentals not there. I can't understand the codeflow when its so logically written.

https://jsfiddle.net/nd6gktmf/

```
var array_length = attack_list.length;
//EDITED: declare local variables
var coordinates,
    origin_longitude,
    origin_latitude,
    dest_longitude,
    dest_latitude;

for(var i=0; i < array_length; i++) {
   coordinates = attack_list[i];
   //EDITED: consider using dot notation
   origin_longitude = coordinates.origin.longitude;
   origin_latitude = coordinates.origin.latitude;
   dest_longitude = coordinates.destination.longitude;
   dest_latitude = coordinates.destination.latitude;

   draw_arc(origin_longitude, origin_latitude, dest_longitude, dest_latitude);
}
```

This Works only in debug mode! What the....

```
function draw_arc(origin_longitude, origin_latitude, dest_longitude, dest_latitude) {
    var data_to_map = 
        [{ 
            origin: {
                latitude: origin_latitude,
                longitude: origin_longitude
            },
            destination: {
                latitude: dest_latitude,
                longitude: dest_longitude 
            }
        }]; 

   console.log("****** Begin******");
   console.log(origin_longitude);
   console.log(origin_latitude);
   console.log(dest_longitude);
   console.log(dest_latitude);
   console.log("****** End ******");

   election.arc(data_to_map, {strokeWidth: 2});
}
```

Comment: To Be Frank: I coded this but I am not sure I even understand how this code is flowing on my computer?!? I am sitting here screaming at my machine.

Comment: Is this what you're trying to do? https://jsfiddle.net/nd6gktmf/1/ if so, then you were WAY overthinking it.

Comment: Kevin; I am trying to Draw each arc one at a time.... and sleep in between each draw.

Comment: Ah, well you can't use a for loop then, and you'll need to use some kind of callback on the arc method.

Comment: Kevin: I am a new javascript developer, and I was given the job to diagram network packet flow using this library.  I have a list of elements, i just want to step by step go through, draw, sleep, and erase.

Comment: Kevin; What is the Loop structure then? Why can't you use a for loopo

Comment: because you can't pause javascript. If the thread isn't running, the browser isn't rendering anything (including the arc)

Comment: Look at it this way. Javascript has this thing called an Event loop, then it has a call stack. Until the call stack is empty, the event loop doesn't run. If the event loop isn't running, the browser can't update the ui because the renderer can't run. the callstack won't be empty until after your for loop completes. That is why you can't pause a for loop.

Comment: Kevin: Alright, than how do people ... loop through objects like this? What is the method to iterate and call things

Comment: You would need a function that calls itself when the thing it is doing is complete. `function foo () {doSomething(foo);}` where `doSomething` is some asynchronous action (such as .arc) that has a callback. I can't find documentation on `.arc` so i have no idea if it accepts a callback. for further research/examples, search "recursive function"

Comment: Gavriel: Why not just provide it the attack_item and push that to election.arc()?  Your solution works, but since I can't follow it.... I am requesting help or explanation. You see your forEach statement should be passing the attack_item, which should ultimately be slammed into the ARC funciton? Why are you leveraging the draw_list array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Kevin pointed out: Delete all the javascript code you added to your question (of course leave your data: `election` and `attack_list`) and replace it with:

```
// loop over the attack_list
attack_list.forEach(function(attack_item, i){
  // now attack_item is one item from the array, i is the index in the array
  // we set up a timer FOR EACH item in the array
  setTimeout(function(){
    // we make an empty array, because election.arc needs an array,
    // eventhough we'll only send 1 item in it, we wrap it in an array
    var draw_list = [];
    draw_list.push(attack_item);
    // put the item into the array
    election.arc(draw_list,{strokeWidth: 2});
  }, i*2000);
  // note: the time is i*2000ms = i*2s
  // the "1st" item in attack_list is at index 0
  // so 0*2000=0 => it'll start drawing it immediately (t=0)
  // it animates for about 1s (t=1)
  // the last drawn line is still displayed (t=1..2)
  //
  // t=2: now the timer for the "2nd" item (i=1) starts drawing
  // but because we created a new empty array and only added the 2nd item
  // into it, when it draws, it erases everything that we drew before
  // and now you only see the 2nd item is getting animated.
  // etc...
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/flocsy/nd6gktmf/3/

Comment: Gavriel: That will draw EVERYTHING at once, i am trying to draw each arc one at a time with a sleep in between.

Comment: I see. Have a look at my last edit, with updated jsfiddle

Comment: Gavriel: I am so sorry, but can you explain why this works and what I wrote didn't. I feel so helpless at the moment!  I can't figure out why my code just didn't work, especially with that awesome function i wrote?!

Comment: Why is there a global draw_list?

Comment: Why not just provide it the attack_item and push that to election.arc()?

Comment: The Attack_item is the exact thing to draw? Why not push that to the arc draw function.

Comment: @Vic wouldn't that result in each iteration erasing previous arcs and only drawing the next?

Comment: Yes it does. That's why you gotta append to your array every time, so those that were already there are still visible. For some reason they don't 'appear' to be redrawn.

Comment: I am trying to show it one a time draw, pause, and disappear. To emulate traffic.

Comment: var draw_list = [];
attack_list.forEach(function(v, i){
  setTimeout(function(){
    draw_list[i] = attack_list[i];
    election.arc(draw_list,{strokeWidth: 2});
    draw_list= [];
  }, i*1000);

Comment: @phnexd: If what you said is correct, by erasing draw_list; I should be able to mimic the following: 1) Draw an Item, 2)Wait for i * 1000 seconds (?) 3) erase last item, draw new item

Comment: Gavriel: yes. Could you sort of walk through your code, and explain why and what it does. I am so sorry, i feel so pathetic. I thought I was a good coder, until today.

Comment: The difference is that the array is redeclared inside the setTimeout which puts it in a different scope. It is redeclared as empty everytime. When it is outside, we append an element to the end so it gets bigger and bigger.

Comment: The setTimeout is used to delay the execution of the function. Though it does not make the forEach go 'slower'. For each attack_item, we increment the delay using the item index (i) * 1000. All the inner executions are setup at once, but executed one after the other with a delay.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the doc, it seems like you gotta put all of your arcs in the same array.

Calling election.arc probably re-renders the entire image which is why you can only see the last one in the end.

Comment: Not True:  If you look at this example and the source code... You can step by step put stuff in.  See Here: http://datamaps.github.io/old

Comment: The problem is my horrid javascript skills. I am trying to loop through an object VS having it called recursively.